# Assign loss probability based on experience

Tags: r

For a school project I am trying to create a dataset in R which contains four variables so far I have:
I have a data.frame which contains the variables: Loss Experience (0,1) ; Loss Size (between 0 and 1) ; Region ; and experience of the driver

I would like to assign now the experience of the driver with a negative correlation to the loss experience ; (in example: the more experienced the driver the less likely an accident occurs. However I still want to have some accidents occurring in case a driver is experienced. Would anyone know how I could do this? Because as of now I am just assigning the experience randomly.

```
Experience_Class <- c(0,100,250,500,1000) #this variable is used to assign different classes of experience levels
Experience <- sample(Experience_Class,N,replace=TRUE)   # this is how I assign the experience to the drivers, however I have the problem that this is completely random
```

My Dataframe should ideally look like this - which a negative correlation between accident occurred and driver experience.

```
Accident_Occured   Accident_Size  Driver_Experience
 1                  .24            0
 1                  0.99           250
 0                  0              0
 0                  0              1000     
 0                  0              500
 0                  0              0
 0                  0              250
 0                  0              1000
 0                  0              1000     
 1                  0.99           100
```

Is this possible? If so, could anyone help me and give me some idea how to assign the experience vector to the loss occurrence vector?

Any thoughts or inputs highly appreciated!

Comment: I was thinking I could solve the problem by creating a variable which is either high or low and then use something like if accident occurred=1 probability of driver being high<10%. And then in a second step I would replace the high low with different values?

Comment: Could you maybe start with the driver experience? E.g. a value between 0 and 1 (which can be created via `runif`). Then you could use a Bernoulli trial to determine whether an accident happend. The accident size itself can also be Uniformly distributed. You just create a vector of size n and multiply it with the variable that determines whether the accident occured.

Comment: Thank you for helping me out here - the way I understand below solution this is what he did right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward. You need to simulate experience based on differential experience by accident. This is a conditional probability problem. P(Exp|accident = 1) = A, P(Exp|accident = 0) = B.

Here's an example. Obviously you can modify it based on **exactly** how you want to run your simulation.

```
set.seed(2314L)
dat <- data.frame(accident= sample(c(0,1), size= 20, replace=T, prob= c(.7,.3)),
                  accident_size= (ifelse(runif(20) < .8, 0, runif(20, .2, 1))))

Experience_Class <- c(0,100,250,500,1000) 
dat$experience <- ifelse(dat$accident == 1, 
                         sample(Experience_Class, size= sum(dat$accident), replace= T, prob= c(.5,.2,.1,.1,.1)),
                         sample(Experience_Class, size= 20-sum(dat$accident), replace= T, prob= c(.05,.05,.2,.3,.4)))

# see results.
R> tapply(dat$experience, dat$accident, mean)
        0         1 
500.00000  33.33333 
R> tapply(dat$experience, dat$accident, sd)
        0         1 
233.85359  57.73503
```

*Also, I wouldn't call the measure of association between two categorical variables correlation.*

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. 
I think this answers my question however, when going through your code I did not really understand the part : 
accident_size= (ifelse(runif(20) < .8, 0, runif(20, .2, 1))))

What does this part of the code exactly do? I understand that runif(n,min,max) so how come you have this equation with runif(20)<0.8, runif(20,0.2,1)


Also I did not understand why you need to take the sum here: 
sample(Experience_Class, size= sum(dat$accident), replace= T, prob= c(.5,.2,.1,.1,.1)),

Highly appreciate if anyone can explain that to me!

Comment: @Alex_T_86 I'm building a dummy dataset that attempts to replicate yours. You didn't specify the data generating mechanism for yours, so I made one up... For additional clarification, I suggest your review the documentation `?sample`.

Comment: Hi Alex, thank you for your help. I understand that, I'd actually like to go with this however I did not understand that part of the code: (ifelse(runif(20) < .8, 0, runif(20, .2, 1)))) <-- this one I still don't get


Could you just elaborate a little further? 
Best regards,
Alex

Comment: Btw. I generated the loss data based on a binomial distrubition but the way I see this actually it does not really make much of a difference to the way you did it. So I'll just go with your part of the code here.

Comment: @Alex_T_86 I saw you had mostly 0's and some values in (.2,1]. So I used a hurdle model with a high threshhold to generate the obs -- `ifelse(runif(20) < .8, 0, runif(20,.2,1))`... if the answer was helpful, upvotes appreciated

Comment: I did upvote, but the problem is I don't have enough reputation so it's not publicly shown ;-)
Just one question, when I look at the data there is no connection between the variables accident and accident size meaning that some observation "had an accident" but the size is zero. Also some observation did not have an accident but the accident size is bigger than zero. How can I adjust this in the code above? Basically only observations with an accident should have accident size bigger than zero. BR